# Json array error Cannot set property 'model' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
var temp = [{}]
var as = ['a', 'b']
for (i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp[i].model = as[i]
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot set property 'model' of undefined

Comment: where you declared `data` in your code?

Comment: where you declared `arr' in your code?

Comment: That happens when `i == 1`, because `temp[1]` is not defined; temporary fix: `var temp = [{}, {}];`

Comment: so what can i do for that ? @Ja͢ck

Comment: but thats only for two val i don't know the length var temp = [{}, {},....]; @Jack

Comment: indeed, so you need to use what Cerbrus suggested.

Comment: I would stay away from using key-words as variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this should do the trick for you:

```
var temp = [];
var as = ['a', 'b'];
for (i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = temp[i] || {};
    temp[i].model = as[i];
}
```

Because `as` can be longer than `temp`, you need to make sure `temp[i]` exists, which is exactly what `temp[i] = temp[i] || {};` does:

- If `temp[i]` exists, it does nothing.
- If `temp[i]` doesn't exist, it assigns a new empty object (`{}`) to `temp[i]`.

Notice that I removed the `{}` from `temp = [{}]` --> `temp = []`. You don't need that first empty object in there, now.

---

If you're absolutely certain `temp` will never contain any values before the loop, you can just do this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = { model: as[i] };
}
```

Or:

```
temp = as.map(function(item){ return { model: item }});
```

Comment: With this in place you can also start with an empty array :)

Comment: It may also be worth pushing the new object in to the array, otherwise it will be lost after the iteration completes.

Comment: @Ja͢ck: Good call, thanks. Rory: I don't quite follow... What object is lost?

Comment: @surajrawat: Is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: @Cerbrus Now got Your explanation .. Thanks ... accepting your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Length of `temp` is 1, length of `as` is 2. `temp[1]` is thus undefined.

I think this communicates the intention of the code better, and is correct:

```
var temp = [];
var as = ['a', 'b'];

for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = {model: as[i]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To always have enough values in `temp` you could populate it beforehand:

```
var as = ['a', 'b'];
var temp = as.map(function() { return {}; });
for (i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp[i].model = as[i]
}
```

Comment: This loops over `as` twice. Not how I'd do it to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, it does that; but the code presented by OP already seems to assume there should be something there, like, something other than just `{}`. In any case, it's just a different vantage point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var temp = [];
var as = ['a', 'b']
for (i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    temp.push({'model':as[i]});
}
console.log(temp);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8k77amwz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple.

use this below for your problem.

```
> var temp =[[]]; var as = ['a','b'] for(i=0;i<as.length;i++){  
> temp.push({model : as[i]}) }
> 
> console.log(temp)
```

Let me know if you have any clarification